# How to create function which return var dictionary<int,string>

Tags: c#

i would like to create function which would replace below code responsible for creating combobox items.

I would like to return var items = new Dictionary();

```
private void cboSection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var items = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    sqlCon.OpenConection();

    query = "sql question";
    SqlDataReader dr = sqlCon.DataReader(query);

    if (dr.HasRows) { cboWorkPlace.Enabled = true; }
    else { cboWorkPlace.Enabled = false; items.Add(0, "--Wybierz--"); }

    items.Add(0, "--Select--");

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        items.Add(Int32.Parse(dr["IdPlace"].ToString()), dr["WorkPlace"].ToString());
    }
    dr.Close();

    cboWorkPlace.DataSource = new BindingSource(items, null);
    cboWorkPlace.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cboWorkPlace.ValueMember = "Key";
    items.Clear();

    sqlCon.CloseConnection();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to create this function ;)

Comment: im starting learn c# and i dont know how to do it

Comment: Which function?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+creating+functions

Comment: i didn't know it was so easy... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap it into a method like this.

```
private Dictionary<int, string> GetComboBoxDictionary()
{
    // Your code here
}
```

I didn't put in your code right away since it seems like your code is missing some tuning. There are statements which don't really make sense to me like the items. For example the Clear at the end there and also it's not formattet well.
I don't know if I should fix that or leave that up to you since it seems like this isn't the question.

Comment: Your formatting on the if-statement isn't very readable. Furthermore you are clearing the dictionary before using it which also seems very weird to me. I don't know where and how you are declaring the SqlConnection but this also seems like it could be slightly improved. This is only talking some small things I saw. When looking at the actual code it's very unclear to me what it should do. You're adding a hardcoded value to the dict inside the else which will also be added after the if (this will even throw an exception), can you explain that?

Comment: By the way you posted the content of my answer yourself in a new answer. This doesn't add anything and will possibly get downvoted. If you see the correct answer you should upvote and accept it.

Comment: sql connection -> i made another class which is responsible for connect to db.

Comment: public void OpenConection()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            con.Open();
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            con.Close();
        }

Comment: I don't know the bigger picture of the application so I can't tell if this is the right way to do it but it seems odd to me. By the way please don't post code in comments but instead edit your question. Also see my updated comment for some questions about what I don't understand in your code.

Comment: ok, else statemend was wrong, should be olny enabled false. Any way thx for help. ;)

Comment: Hope I was still able to help. If you find my answer helpful please consider upvoting/accepting it :). If you need more help with your code feel free to ask I'll try to help anywhere I can. Also I would suggest deleting [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56431388/10883465) since it doesn't add to the question itself (and shouldn't post code-only answers anyway).